# Foreign key not saving rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to save a product which belongs_to category with foreign_key :category_id.  The failed product.save is show below:

```
Processing by ProductsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"2V3zVrgU3SoGAwyHDLYQuyDFWq9rI7U4GdDeZNDRwrLTwsGloio4MIXUOdU/ckvnTsMGF9B9TL4tuNWKSqZpVg==", "product"=>{"name"=>"trek"}, "commit"=>"Save Product", "category_id"=>"1"}
```

Everytime I try to save the product it says "category must exist".  I understand I have my models and migrations a little off, but can't figure out how.  Below are the files.

product.rb:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category   
end
```

category.rb: empty

create_categories.rb:

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

create_products.rb:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.belongs_to :category, index: {unique: true}, foreign_key: true,  null: $

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I can also post my product_controller.rb however it is pretty standard with just @product.save and a redirect_to products_path or 'products#index'.

Thank you.

EDIT:  products_controller.rb:

```
def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to category_products_path([@category, @product])$
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_enti$
      end
    end
  end

def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit( :name, :category_id)
    end
```

Comment: your product belongs to a category, thus while creating a product you need to pass a category_id. If you want to bypass category, then in the model use `optional: true`.
could you post your controller code?

Comment: I do pass :category_id in product_params, however still doesn't save, I will edit with my products_controller.rb, thank you.

Comment: Your `category_id` is outside your `product` hash. Without seeing your controller, that seems suspicious.

Comment: Yes, frustrating, I have tried multiple code arrangement but it seems to do that everytime. How can I fix that?

Comment: `null: $` - what?

Comment: I think those `$`s must be an editor problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to do something like:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @product = @category.products.new(product_params)
    if @product.save
      format.html { redirect_to category_products_path([@category, @product]) }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end

private

  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name, :category_id)
  end

end
```

This assumes, naturally, that you have something like:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products 
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category 
end
```

As you currently have it written, there are at least a couple of problems.

First, you say:

```
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit( :name, :category_id)
end
```

But, `params[:product]` doesn't have `category_id`.

Second, you say:

```
format.html { redirect_to category_products_path([@category, @product])}
```

But, you don't define `@category`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176778/discussion-on-answer-by-jvillian-foreign-key-not-saving-rails-5).

Answer (score 0):

You should find the category from the category id, then under that category create product.

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @product = @category.products.new(product_params)
    if @product.save
      format.html { redirect_to category_products_path([@category, @product]) }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
    end
  end

private

  def product_params
    # as your category_id is outside of product hash, doesn't need to permit in product hash though
    params.require(:product).permit(:name)
  end

end
```

In your **product/_form.html.erb** create the `form_for` with nested resources, then you'll get the category_id under `params[:product]` hash.

Comment: I assumed those trailing dollar signs were an error. Look weird, don't they?

Comment: thanks, that now gives me an error in products#new, undefined method `name' for :product:Symbol